# Why do we need to require and include a module for a class?

Tags: ruby

Why do I need to require `"stacklike"` in `stack.rb` when I am already using the include method for the `stacklike.rb`? If I remove the `require`, it yields the error `"Uninitialized constant Stack::Stacklike (NameError)"`.

stacklike.rb

```
module Stacklike
  def stack
    @stack ||= []  #@stack || @stack = []
  end
  def add_to_stack(obj)
    stack.push(obj)
  end
  def take_from_stack
    stack.pop
  end
end
```

stack.rb

```
require_relative "stacklike"
class Stack
  include Stacklike
end

s = Stack.new
s.add_to_stack("people")
s.add_to_stack("people2")
s.add_to_stack("people3")

puts "obj currently on the stack:"
puts s.stack

taken = s.take_from_stack
puts "Removed this stack:"
puts taken

puts "Now on stack:"
puts s.stack
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby's `include` doesn't access the file system. The given module must have already been defined or a `NameError` will be raised:

```
# foo.rb
class Foo
  include Bar  # NameError: uninitialized constant Foo::Bar
end
```

This works (everything in one file):

```
# foo.rb
module Bar
end

class Foo
  include Bar
end
```

If your module is defined in a separate file, you have to load this file using `require` or `require_relative`:

```
# bar.rb
module Bar
end

# foo.rb
require_relative 'bar'
class Foo
  include Bar
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`require` is about files. `include` is about modules. Since a module and a file does not correspond one-to-one in Ruby, requiring a file and including a module are different tasks. They need to be controlled separately.

The content of the module `Stacklike` is written on the file `stacklike.rb`, so you need to require that file to access the module. Then, you need to include `Stack` if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

We use [`Module#include`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-include) method with module names as parameter to that method, to add those modules in the requiring class's ancestor chain. Now [`Kernel#require_relative`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-require_relative) will made available the classes,modules etc from the requiring file to the required file on top level.

When you did `require_relative "stacklike"`,it means module(s),class(s) etc whichever you have defined inside the file `stacklike.rb` are now available to the top level of the file `stack.rb`. Now to use the instance methods of the module `Stacklike`,using the instance of the class `Stack`,you need to include that module to the class `Stack`.